# Why does .title(for: .normal) return nil for Plain styles in UIKit

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uikit

I'm following the Apple Pie project from Apple's [Develop in Swift Fundamentals](https://books.apple.com/us/book/develop-in-swift-fundamentals/id1556365994) book (pp. 333 - 362). There was a weird error where getting a button's title seemed to cause an exception.

`"Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"`

```
@IBAction func letterButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    sender.isEnabled = false
    let letterString = sender.title(for: .normal)! <-- offending code
    let letter = Character(letterString.lowercased())
}
```

I figured out the fix which involved setting the button's `Style` to default instead of `Plain`. However, I don't understand why the `Plain` style would return nil in the first place. Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Plain styles are new and behave differently. That's a completely new setup for buttons introduced because of SwiftUI. See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibutton/configuration . You would probably get the title using `button.configuration.title`.

Comment: I don't know why but i checked what you've say but everything works fine for me, switch button to plain or default both of them gives me the title using your code, If you want I can share my images with you

Comment: @Sulthan I just copied the code from the book and this was built for XCode 12. I'm using XCode 13 so perhaps some things work differently now. I guess it's not backward compatible.

Comment: @RezaKhonsari What version of XCode are you using? I wonder if it's a version issue.

Comment: @Paul I'm using 13.2

Comment: @RezaKhonsari That's interesting. Others I worked with had the same issue. I'm not sure if its a version issue or something else then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I figured out the fix which involved setting the button's Style to default instead of Plain.

I think this is because when you set the style to "Plain", you are effectively using the [`UIButton.Configuration`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibutton/configuration/) API introduced in iOS 15. You are basically doing something like this:

```
button.configuration = .plain()
```

And setting the title in the storyboard would set the `title` of the `configuration`, rather than calling `setTitle(_:for:)`. You can think of this as:

```
 button.configuration?.title = "..."
```

This is why you can't get the title using `title(for:)`, but you should be able to get the title you set in the storyboard using `button.configuration?.title`.

Comment: So there is no way to set the title in the IB? Does it have to be in code?

Comment: @Houman you can set it in IB too. The OP did exactly that.