# How do you set the so-called "Style" - Xcode storyboard - of a UIButton, in code?

Tags: swift, xcode, uibutton

[image]

Notice the "Type". In fact you get to that in code with `.buttonType` or indeed with the UIButton constructor.

But what the hell is the "Style"?

How do you set that in code, say, to Plain?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That corresponds to the [`configuration`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibutton/3784627-configuration) property. The 4 non-default options in the picker in IB corresponds

```
button.configuration = .plain()
button.configuration = .gray()
button.configuration = .filled()
button.configuration = .tinted()
```

When any of these four options are selected, changing the button's property using the properties panel generally corresponds to setting one of the properties of [`UIButton.Configuration`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibutton/configuration), rather than `UIButton`. See also: [Why does .title(for: .normal) return nil for Plain styles in UIKit](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71257406/5133585)

Note that there is also the "Default" option, which corresponds to

```
button.configuration = nil
```

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH !  (Very often the "Default" one is best - now I know it's nil thanks to you.)